# Automatic move all mails to folder

Tags: mail.app, backup, automation, exchange-activesync

I have a School email (Microsoft Exchange) which is limited to 350MB of storage. Therefore every month or two I need to move all my emails to the Mac drive instead of the Exchange server.

One thing I noticed is that the Exchange automatically sends a reminder that my storage is nearly full, and I think this reminder could be used to trigger an event that moves all of my Exchange email to a backup folder on my Mac.

Reminder > Select ALL Exchange email (not All Mail) > Move to Exchange Backup (Local folder)

Is there any chance this could be done?

(Bonus: when the emails are moved, is it possible that all the emails on the Exchange server are permanently deleted?)

Comment: Just to verify: Is that MegaBytes (MB) or MegaBits (Mb)?

Comment: Sorry meant MB. edited question.